# RStudio syntax formatting - Bold function names

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm reading through Hadley Wickham's [Advanced-R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) web text and noticed that the code is shown has syntax highlighting that bolds the names of functions. I find this incredibly easy to read and I was wondering how I might be able to apply that to my own code?

Reference:

[image: bold function names]

Comment: This sounds like a question for RStudio support, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You might find the formatting details in this package:

> [Bookdown](https://github.com/hadley/bookdown): 
>   The bookdown package is used to power http://adv-r.had.co.nz

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of RStudio (I'm working with v1.1.4), you can enable an option to highlight functions calls.

Simply check the box in `Tools > Global options > Code > Display > "Highlight R functions calls"`.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of every page of Hadley's online book, you will see

> © Hadley Wickham. Powered by [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/), and [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). Source available on [github](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/)

That's probably the best place to look.

Comment: In an effort to reduce wasted time, I'm assuming this is a function of jekyll or pandoc and not an internal capability of RStudio.

Thanks